# Enabling eglfs in buildroot for Qt - stm32mp1

Tags: linux, qt, embedded, buildroot

Which package should provide eglfs for Qt for stm32mp1? Tried a couple and the eglfs is not being deployed.

Answer (score 0):

You should add more detail in your question, and attach any error log you have. Are you trying to compile Qt with eglfs support Or you are trying to run Qt with eglfs?
- if you are trying to compiling Qt, to enable elgfs, of course you need EGL. Please attach your build log so that your issue will be more clear.
- if you are trying to run Qt with eglfs, what is the error message look like?

Comment: As an amateur somehow I'm getting more success with yocto so I'll stick with that for a while. But thanks anyway. Should I delete the question?